# Polymer component paper stepper by zecat is having back navigation issue

Tags: polymer, web-component, stepper

I am using a paper stepper polymer component by zecat (http://zecat.github.io/paper-stepper/components/paper-stepper/)
My issue is as below.

- All the steps from 1 to 5 are showing correctly.
- I can navigate from a previous step to any future steps. Eg. From Step 1 to Step 2 or Step 3, From Step 2 to Step 3 or step 5.
- My problem is, i cant select a previous step, but i can navigate it by back button. Eg. from Step 3 , Step 2 or Step 1 is not clickable.

I tries with all the attributes like editable,completed, selectable ect, but nothing is working. Here is my code:

```
        <paper-stepper  id="wizardStepper" alternative-label has-back-button has-skip-button selected={{selectedIndex}} finish-text="Yes" continue-text="Yes" update-text="Yes">
        <paper-step id="internetStepId" label="Internet & VPN" >
            <div class="wizard-content-div">
                <h4>Network Configurations</h4>

            </div>
        </paper-step>


        <paper-step id="customerDataStepId" label="360 Customer Data"  >
            <div class="wizard-content-div">
                <h4>Customer Data</h4>

            </div>
        </paper-step>

        <paper-step id="inboundConnectorStepId" label="Inbound Connectors"  >
            <div class="wizard-content-div">
                <h4>Inbound connectors</h4>

            </div>
        </paper-step>


        <paper-step id="outboundConnectorStepId" label="Outbound Connectors"  >
            <div class="wizard-content-div">
                <h4>outbound connector</h4>

            </div>
        </paper-step>


        <paper-step id="marketingCampaignStepId" label="Marketing Campaigns"  >
            <div class="wizard-content-div">
                <h4>marketing campaign</h4>

            </div>
        </paper-step>

    </paper-stepper>
```

Comment: Then raise an issue with the creator: https://github.com/zecat

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this issue. The steps which are previous to the currently selected step is disabled because of the lower  z-index value of css.
You need to give a z-index value which is greater than currently selected step.